# Return all Requests to Index in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

For nginx, how can I return all Requests (of a dir) to the index?

ex:

user requests: /link/to/garbage/w/w/w/w/whatever
nginx moves request to /link/index.php

if possible, return as a query? like index.php?search={request}

the server block in question:

```
location /pages {
include fast go.conf;
}
```

Comment: What `location` blocks do you have in your configuration?

Comment: i have 3,
```
location / {
 (php passthrough stuff)
like normal
};
location /page {
(php stuff)

}
```
and one for my crappy API (they just pass it to php FPM, nothing else happens

Comment: If you edit your question and add the `server` block, it will make it easier for people to make suggestions.

Comment: done. I added the block